# Morphological Operations On Image

Tags: c#, opencv, image-processing, emgucv, image-morphology

I am currently doing a project in which I am trying to identify humans based on hands vascular pattern in C# using Emgu CV.
The gray-scale image of the hand was first processed using the Adaptive Threshold function.
Now I want to create a mask of the image using the morphological operations.
The purpose is to remove the noise from the image.
This is the adaptive-thresholded image:

[image]

Kindly guide me which function should I use and how to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code here is in C++. It shouldn't be difficult to port to C#, since it's mostly OpenCV functions calls. You can use that as guideline. Sorry about that.

---

You can apply a *open* operation with a small kernel to remove most of the noise:

```
Mat1b opened;
Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
morphologyEx(thresholded, opened, MORPH_OPEN, kernel);
```

[image]

As you can see, some noise is still present, and you can't remove it with other morphological operations. You can simply consider the largest blob as the correct one (in green here):

[image]

Then you can floodfill the inside of the hand (in gray here):

[image]

And set to 0 all values in original image where the corresponding mask in not the same color of the inside of the image:

[image]

This is the full code (again, it's C++):

```
        #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
    using namespace cv;

    int main(int, char**)
    {
        // Load grayscale image
        Mat1b thresholded = imread("path_to_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

        // Get rid of JPEG compression artifacts
        thresholded = thresholded > 100;

        // Needed so findContours handles borders contours correctly
        Mat1b bin;
        copyMakeBorder(thresholded, bin, 1,1,1,1, BORDER_CONSTANT, 0);

        // Apply morphological operation "close"
        Mat1b closed;
        Mat kernel = getStructuringElement(MORPH_ELLIPSE, Size(3, 3));
        morphologyEx(bin, closed, MORPH_OPEN, kernel);

        // Find contours
        vector<vector<Point>> contours;
        findContours(bin.clone(), contours, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Point(-1,-1)); // Point(-1,-1) accounts for previous copyMakeBorder

        // Keep largest contour
        int size_largest = 0;
        int idx_largest = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < contours.size(); ++i)
        {
            if (contours[i].size() > size_largest)
            {
                size_largest = contours[i].size();
                idx_largest = i;
            }
        }

        Mat3b dbg;
        cvtColor(closed, dbg, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);


        // Black initialized mask
        Mat1b mask(thresholded.rows, thresholded.cols, uchar(0));

        if (idx_largest >= 0)
        {
            drawContours(dbg, contours, idx_largest, Scalar(0, 255, 0), CV_FILLED);

            // Draw filled polygin on mask
            drawContours(mask, contours, idx_largest, Scalar(255), 1);
        }

        // Get a point inside the contour
        Moments m = moments(contours[idx_largest]);
        Point2f inside(m.m10 / m.m00, m.m01 / m.m00);

        floodFill(mask, inside, Scalar(127));

        Mat3b result;
        cvtColor(thresholded, result, COLOR_GRAY2BGR);
        result.setTo(Scalar(0), mask != 127);


        imshow("Closed", closed);
        imshow("Contour", dbg);
        imshow("Result", result);
        waitKey();

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks man. It helped a lot. The issue i am facing is that if you see the original image you will find the the veins are in the thin black lines. With your method all the details inside the hand are gone. I don't want to loose those details while removing the noise outside the hand region.

Comment: Check now, let me know

Comment: Alright. I will let you know in a while after giving it multiple tries With the image results.

Comment: I have checked it. It works. The issue is there are some functions that can't be used in C#. How to do that

Comment: Glad it works. No idea about that. C# is not my stuff ;D. Which functions are not supported by emgucv?

Comment: Mat1b, vector<vector>

Comment: well, I'm pretty sure that emgucv has the equivalent for the `Mat` of type `CV_8UC1`, and has `Contour<Point> ` for the other. See [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/html/028cb9c4-eb4b-aa5d-242e-273ac7e227e2.htm)

Comment: Miki. There is a little confusion in this code. I need to perform another operation on the masked image. The image we obtain after flood fill , it contains extra white lines  as border around the image of hand. I want those lines to merged with the background color. Actually I don't want those lines to visible. Second thing I want is the color of the flood filled area to be white not gray. You help is much needed.

Comment: @JunaidSultan This is a different problem, so please ask a different question