# Image Processing on flood fill image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am working on an image processing project in which I have flood filled the original image.

Now

1. I  need to remove the noise in this picture which is the white lines around the image of the hand. I want to remove these white lines by merging them into the background color which is black.
2. I need to to change the gray color (the value is `127`) of the flood filled area to white color. Note that the background colour should remain black.

[image]

---

This is a follow-up of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35460986/5008845). The image is obtained with the code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35461437/5008845).

Comment: okay cool. What did you try so far?

Comment: what did you flood in this image ?

Comment: Look at two possible solutions:
1. Scale image down. It will remove small features, though, not completely.
2. Do erosion, then dilation. It will completely remove features smaller than erosion/dilation radius.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code to produce the image in your question can be found in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35461437/5008845).

So we know that the flood-filled region has value `127`.

---

Starting from this image, you can easily obtain the mask of the flood-filled region as:

```
Mat1b mask = (img == 127);
```

[image]

The single channel mask will have values either black `0` or white `255`.

If you want to have a color image, you need to create a black initialized image of the same size as `img`, and set pixels according to the mask to your favourite color (green here):

```
// Black initialized image, same size as img
Mat3b out(img.rows, img.cols, Vec3b(0,0,0)); 

Scalar some_color(0,255,0);
out.setTo(some_color, mask);
```

[image]

Code for reference:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    Mat1b img = imread("path_to_floodfilled_image", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    // 127 is the color of the floodfilled region
    Mat1b mask = (img == 127); 

    // Black initialized image, same size as img
    Mat3b out(img.rows, img.cols, Vec3b(0,0,0)); 

    Scalar some_color(0,255,0);
    out.setTo(some_color, mask);

    // Show results
    imshow("Flood filled image", img);
    imshow("Mask", mask);
    imshow("Colored mask", out);
    waitKey();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou. This one works. You have always been so helpful.

Comment: Please Check the answer below this comment

Comment: I have asked the question in a new post. Please Check it . :)

Comment: @JunaidSultan I've seen that, but I'm too busy now ;D. Also, I don't think that the multiplication makes much sense ...

Comment: So which method would you suggest ?